# How to set an image field in django to an image file on S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a [django model](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) (Page) with an image field, with files stored on S3. I can upload and delete images just fine using boto3, but I'm trying to implement a gallery feature, where the user can select from a series of photos already on S3 and then set the Page's image to the selected photo.

It seems that if i do page.picture.save(....), I need to pass the filename and the content for it to upload the file to S3 again, but this seems a bit redundant since the file is already on S3. Is it possible to just point the image field to the relevant src?